# multiple train, test sets equally grouped

Tags: r, apply

I have a df containing with data for three years.

```r
df <- data.table( YEAR = c("1999", "1999", "2000", "1999","2000", 
                           "2000","1999", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001"),
                  Sex=c("M", "F","F", "M","M", "F","F", "F", "M", "F","F", "M"),
                  V3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                  V4 = rnorm(12, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

The number of rows  is the same for each year.
I want to create 3 linear regression models, one for each year . The size of the train set for each year should be the same across years. For instance, 3 instances for train and 1 for test for each year. 
I know there are many posibilites of doing it for one year, like:

```
df_1999 <- df1 %>% 
filter (YEAR == 1999)  

samp <- sample(nrow(df_1999), 0.75 * nrow(df_1999)) 
train <- df[samp, ]
test <- df[-samp, ]

model_1999 <- lm(V4 ~ V3+ factor(Sex), data = df_1999)
```

but I don't know how to get this at once in order to fit each of the lm model .

Comment: Hi, you should add tags about the techs you are talking about, don’t you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of a split and apply problem.  I would use the `split()` function to split the original dataframe by year and then us lapply to perform the linear regression on each subset of the data.

```
df <- data.frame( YEAR = c("1999", "1999", "2000", "1999","2000", 
                           "2000","1999", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001"),
                  Sex=c("M", "F","F", "M","M", "F","F", "F", "M", "F","F", "M"),
                  V3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                  V4 = rnorm(12, mean = 0, sd = 1))

dfs<-split(df, df$YEAR)
set.seed(1)
lapply(dfs, function(df){
  samp <- sample(nrow(df), 0.75 * nrow(df)) 
  train <- df[samp, ]
  test <- df[-samp, ]
  model <- lm(V4 ~ V3+ factor(Sex), data = train)
})
```

Note since this the sample data set is small, it the train subset many not contain all possible combinations of the variables and may error.